# How sus is this script I found in a youtube ad?

Tags: cpp-ethereum, scam

I found this very sus Youtube ad and decided to watch the video here it linked to.  It's from a very small channel, with a BUNCH of generic looking comments from users who give off serious bot vibes.  Feels like a crypto scam but I don't have the expertise to pinpoint it since I don't know squat about coding or ETH contracts.  There is a linked series of pasted code for this:

the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ol12hWLvr5o
the code: https://codepastes.com/raw/HKKxGO

I'm sorry if this isn't the correct place to post a question like this, but I do not know where else I'll find reputable people who know more about these things.  I would like to reiterate that this appeared as an ad video, and did not appear in my normal YT feed.

Answer (score 0):

It is a scam contract. There's no reason to use a function to ofuscate an address.

```
// Function getDexRouter returns the DexRouter address
function getDexRouter(bytes32 _DexRouterAddress, bytes32 _factory) internal pure returns (address) {
    return address(uint160(uint256(_DexRouterAddress) ^ uint256(_factory)));
}
```

Comment: Can you find in code scammer adress?

Comment: @JurajJuraj I didn't try. It should be doable.